# С++.Ошибка при инициализации vector значением(ссылкой) из функции

Tags: c++, vector, инициализация

Есть вот такая программа:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int>& getVector()
{
    vector<int> a;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> some = getVector(); //***
}
```

Не подскажите, почему  строка `vector<int> some = getVector()`  выдает ошибку после компиляции?
Примечание: код ниже рабочий.

```
vector<int> some;
some = getVector();
```

Comment: Всё прекрасно компилируется: https://godbolt.org/z/5a8vfE. Правда, в вашем коде UB, о чём честно предупреждает компилятор.

Comment: Ошибка такая: исключение Microsoft C++: std::bad_array_new_length по адресу памяти 0x0017F5D4. Посмотрел я на предупреждение про возврат локальной переменной, и создал vector динамически. Все исправилось, но... почему

Comment: Решение - не создавать вектор динамически, а тупо возвращать по значению вместо ссылки. *"почему"* Потому что `a` уничтожается сразу после выхода из функции, до того, как вы из него читаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, что ошибку выдаёт потому, что ваша функция getVector() возвращает указатель (ссылку) на уже несуществующий экземпляр класса vector, так как он объявлен локальной переменной функции getVector(). Перед возвратом вызывается деструктор, фрейм локальных переменных освобождается. Нельзя возвращать указатели на локальные переменные, никогда!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не могли бы вы сказать, почему тогда в случае : vector<int> some;
some = getVector(); работало, как я упомянул. Или это просто один из случаев неопределенного поведения

Comment: Это - типичное неопределённое поведение. После возврата из процедуры, память под её локальные переменные физически не очищается, а значит эти переменные могут какое-то время быть как бы "доступны", до тех пор, пока их не затрут другие данные. В случае vector<int> some = getVector(), скорее всего, переменная some создаётся после вызова getVector() и затирает собой то, что раньше было переменной a - потому и явная ошибка. А во втором случае some формируется в стеке перед вызовом getVector() и не затирает память с бывшим экземпляром a - вот ошибка как бы не проявилась...

Comment: Но независимо от того, проявилась ошибка, или нет - это всё равно ошибка, и допускать её не стоит))